# Output from UserState Apache Beam doesn't works

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Have DoFn, that writes some int variable from event into state, then trying to read from state and write into GCP. This DoFn called after opening fixed window.

```
class ModelStatefulFn(beam.DoFn):
    BUFFER_STATE = userstate.CombiningValueStateSpec('model_state', coders.IterableCoder(coders.VarIntCoder()),
                                                     combiners.ToListCombineFn())
    EXPIRY_TIMER = userstate.TimerSpec('expiry1', beam.TimeDomain.REAL_TIME)

    def __init__(self, output_path):
        self.output_path = output_path

    def process(self, event, buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE), window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        spin_count = event['data']['eventData'].get('number_of_rounds')
        buffer.add(spin_count)
        window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime().strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
        window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime().strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
        filename = "-".join([self.output_path, window_start, window_end])
        data = ''.join(str(x) for x in sorted(buffer.read()))
        with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filename=filename, mode="w") as f:
            f.write((dumps(data) + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
```

Pipeline works without errors, but has no any outputs.
How to output data from userstates?

Comment: Your code look OK. Do you see elements getting added to the buffer?

Comment: @KennKnowles don't know how to check it without files and logging

Comment: I suggest testing it using the DirectRunner, where you can easily use files, logging, and a debugger. Once your pipeline works as expected on small data, then launch on Dataflow.

Comment: @KennKnowles thanks, will try

Comment: @Degrijo have you tried the Kenn's scenario?

Comment: @Ines Yes, logging doesn't work locally too. But now have exception "Input value to a stateful DoFn or KeyParam must be a KV tuple; instead, got '18964741'."